# EclipseLink: ignore cache and get data directly from database

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

My application is used by many users at the same time, whenever a user makes changes to the database i want the others to be able to reload their entity list with the new data. I managed to do this by using the following code:

```
public List<T> listAll() {
    clearCache();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(clazz);

    Root<T> root = cq.from(clazz);
    CriteriaQuery<T> cquery = cq.select(root);
    List<T> lista = em.createQuery(cquery).setHint(QueryHints.CACHE_RETRIEVE_MODE,
         CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS).getResultList();


    return lista;
}


public void clearCache(){
    em.clear();
}
```

The problem is that i need to add both clearCache and the hint methods everytime i want the current database state. Shouldn't CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS be enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS of EclipseLink is not useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462340/cacheretrievemode-bypass-of-eclipselink-is-not-useful)

Comment: Thanks, already knew about the refresh method, but i was looking for a way to prevent using that specially when i want to get a list of entities.